# TinyMCE removes the ng-click event Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, tinymce

```
editor.insertContent("<a href=\"#\" ng-click=\"signUp()\"> sign up </a>");
```

this is code line my simple pluging for TinyMCE editor.
it work but with some problem. 
The problem with this is that it removes ng-click="signup()" from like. in other words this produce following content

```
<a href="#"> sign up </a>
```

**Intead of**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="signUp()"> sign up </a>
```

I will be thanks full if some help me in this case. I just want to create a small plugin for tinymce insert just above code line in correct way

Comment: read up on editor configuration options for attributes and level of sanitizing. You should be able to whitelist specifc attributes or set configuration to allow all attributes

Comment: following tinymce alloweed me to do this. extended_valid_elements

Comment: reply me with this settinh i will accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set ng-click as valid tinymce attribute of a-Tags. Try this setting:

```
// The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style]," +
"a[name|href|target|title|alt|ng-click]," +
"#p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
"-span,hr",
```

Comment: This works. But I am not able to insert `@click` shorthand for `v-on:click` from VueJS. I tried `@click` and it is still removed. I also tried  `v-on:click` but this converted to `v-on="click"`. How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share my solution too. Might not be suitable for all the use cases as it leaves you vulnerable to XSS. For my closed environment its fine thou.

I also wanted to allow using any other angular attributes, so listing them all isn't very feasible.

I simply added following:

```
valid_elements: '*[*]'
```

This allows using any elements with any attributes.